# Populating a Bootstrap select picker dynamically: change event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap Select picker that I have to create and add to the page's HTML dynamically, after it's been loaded. The problem is that, when I do this, the selectpicker's "change" event doesn't seem to be triggered.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83k458Lz/7/

(Eventually, the data in the dropdown will be loaded through JSON, but in the example I have added it inline).

The code is here:

```
//The jsFiddle has a much more complete list of data
var lista_pueblos=[{"id":"2","nombre":"Madrid"},{"id":"4","nombre":"Barcelona"},{"id":"5","nombre":"Heidelberg"},{"id":"6","nombre":"Dusseldorf"}];

var dropdown='<select id="localidad_origen_1" name="localidad_origen_1" class="form-control selectpicker input-sm localidad_origen" data-live-search="true" required><option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione localidad</option></select>';

$("#formulario").after(dropdown);


rellenaPueblos($("#localidad_origen_1"), -1);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$('.selectpicker').refresh();    



$("body").on('change',".localidad_origen, .localidad_destino", function(){
    alert("Meeept");   
   });


function rellenaPueblos(dd, pueblo_anterior) {
        var cadena="";
        var elProximoEsElBueno=false;
        for (var i = 0; i < lista_pueblos.length; i++) {
            if (elProximoEsElBueno == true) {
                cadena += "<option SELECTED value='" + lista_pueblos[i]["id"] + "'>" + lista_pueblos[i]["nombre"] + "</option>\n";
                elProximoEsElBueno = false;
                }
            else {
                cadena += "<option value='" + lista_pueblos[i]["id"] + "'>" + lista_pueblos[i]["nombre"] + "</option>\n";
                }
            if (lista_pueblos[i]["id"] == pueblo_anterior) {
                elProximoEsElBueno=true;
                }
            }
        //alert(dd.name);
        dd.append(cadena);
        }
```

And the HTML is very simple:

```
<form id="formulario">
</form>
```

As you can see, the dropdown gets populated correctly, but when I pick an option, the "change" event doesn't seem to be triggered. I have read about event delegation, but as you can see, the event handler is attached to `body`. to take advantage of event bubbling.

What else am I missing? I have the suspicion that it must be something really silly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('.selectpicker').refresh();
```

To this:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Calling the non-existent refresh() method prevented the remaining code from being executed.

Corrected fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/83k458Lz/11/